# Jenkins API 403 forbidden C# Http request

Tags: c#, jenkins, curl

I am having trouble using the Jenkins API to reach an endpoint.
My Jenkins is hosted on IIS setup using the following: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+IIS

My IIS site has Windows authentication only - this cannot be changed because it's how the organisation
has established it. 
Therefore, when making the call I need to pass my username and password as my credentials leaving out the API token. When I try a similar request in Curl it says I am authenticated as Anonymous (I cannot change any Jenkins security configurations). Suggesting that the API token is required.

Is there a way I can provide my username, password and API token to overcome this 403 issue in a C# console app OR using Curl?

C# Code

```
            HttpWebRequest initRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://jenkinsdomain.co.uk/api/json?pretty=true");



            initRequest.Method = "GET";

            initRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            initRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");


            try

            {

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)initRequest.GetResponse(); // Raises Unauthorized Exception

                Console.Write(response.StatusCode);

            }

            catch (Exception e)

            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/28632522/5386938 can be of help.

Comment: That did not work. I need to find a way to send my username, password and api token.