# IIS/PHP pass-through login to other IIS

Tags: php, iis

Is it possible to pass credentials from an IIS website with PHP to an IIS .NET website?

On one end I have a IIS website with PHP. Windows Authentication is enabled.
On the other end I have a IIS .NET which handles requests and returns JSON (API). Windows authentication also enabled.

I would like to use PHP/CURL to get information from the .NET website. The CURL to the .NET website return a 401 error. So I guess the credentials are not passed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't cURL work with Windows Authentication on IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094535/why-doesnt-curl-work-with-windows-authentication-on-iis7). See also https://superuser.com/questions/250053/how-can-i-pass-my-windows-credentials-in-curl . You should be able to create the same option using PHP's cURL library, I would expect.